# javascript:popWin() through echo php

Tags: javascript, php, window

How to make JS popup window inside `echo` line?

I have this line but the popup not work :

```
echo '<td> <a href="javascript:popWin(edit.php?id='.$row[id].')">Edit</a></td>';
```

then I check the link location on status bar :

```
javascript:popWin(edit.php?id=12)
```

as what I learn before it should be single quote inside the `popWin()`, but I have no clue to solve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place a literal singlequote in your echo use backslash to escape it:

```
echo '<td> <a href="javascript:popWin(\'edit.php?id='.$row[id].'\')">Edit</a></td>';
```

Comment: Still  wont work, as he wants to set all the content inside the popWin between single quote, and not only the ID.

Comment: @Leandragem good catch, didn't notice that; updating...

Comment: I think that now it will run no prob!

Comment: Bothered to test it this time: https://eval.in/117259

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this echo for this:

```
echo "<td> <a href=\"javascript:popWin('edit.php?id=".$row[id]."')\">Edit</a></td>";
```

When you use double quotes, you can use simple quotes inside the echo without escaping it. (\)